# Laravel Eloquent non-object error

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to familiarize myself with Laravel and the MVC structure by migrating an app written in php to Laravel.

I've set up a controller UserController.php:

```
<?php

class UserController extends BaseController{
public function showUsers(){ 
    // Display all SQL executed in Eloquent
    Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query)
    {
    var_dump($query);
    });
    $users = User::all();
    return View::make('users')->with('users', $users);
}
}
```

Model User.php:

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'users';

public $timestamps = false;

public function ip()
{
    return $this->hasOne('IP', 'user');
}

}
```

and Model IP.php

```
<?php

class IP extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'ips';

public $timestamps = false;

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

}
```

In my view users.blade.php I display select information for all users in a table format like:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
        <td>{{{ $user->lname . ',' . $user->fname }}}</td>
        <td>{{{ $user->ip }}}</td>                    
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

When executed like this I get the array response for the IP address such as:

```
{"id":"257","ip_addr":"167772675","network":"2","user":"00002","router":null,"used":"1"}
```

Which is the correct information for the user displayed for that row.
If I try to get just the desired ip address by:

```
{{{ $user->ip->ip_addr }}}
```

I get the following error:
     ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
     Trying to get property of non-object

The database schema is as follows:
table users:

```
+---------+-------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type                          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | smallint(5) unsigned zerofill | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fname   | varchar(30)                   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lname   | varchar(30)                   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| bname   | varchar(40)                   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| addr1   | varchar(50)                   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| addr2   | varchar(50)                   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city    | varchar(50)                   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| state   | varchar(2)                    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| zip     | varchar(5)                    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email   | varchar(254)                  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phone1  | varchar(12)                   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phone2  | varchar(12)                   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| idate   | date                          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tdate   | date                          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ptype   | int(11)                       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| maddr   | varchar(12)                   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| antenna | int(11)                       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| notes   | text                          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| service | int(11)                       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| company | int(11)                       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| active  | tinyint(1)                    | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| blocked | tinyint(1)                    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------+-------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and table ips:

```
+---------+-------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type                          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)                       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ip_addr | int(10) unsigned              | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| network | int(11)                       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id | smallint(5) unsigned zerofill | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| router  | int(11)                       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| used    | tinyint(1)                    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I've tried a wide variety of variations on the syntax and I'm just treading water at this point. 
Thanks for looking!

Comment: Did you mean `{{{ $user->ip()->ip_addr }}}`?

Comment: @fakemeta that wouldn't be the issue, Eloquent turns those relationships into properties on model objects. @Tom I believe you have a capitilization error in your User relationship, you're relating to `IP` but the class is `Ip`

Comment: Adding the () to the ip returns the following error instead: ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$ip_addr

Comment: @watcher OOps sure did, a remnant from testing with Ip instead of IP or ip. I've corrected it but the issue persists. I'll adjust it on here also. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that not every user has related `ip` so you get `null` from `$user->ip` in the foreach loop. You need to check if relation exists before accessing its proeprty.

Comment: @jarek Thanks for the input Jarek. Can you give a small example of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your User model you define this relationship:

```
public function ip()
{
    return $this->hasOne('IP', 'user');
}
```

You're trying to relate the `User` to an `IP` class, but you don't have an `IP` class, you have an `Ip` class. The relationship is probably failing to load and causing your error.

Furthermore, according to the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships), the second parameter to the `hasOne` method is the foreign key Eloquent should use when relating entries in your database to one another.  In this case it should be the foreign key inside the `users` table that is pointing to the records in the `ips` table.  I don't think you want to use `user` as the parameter there.

Eloquent works with these relationships by specifying the following convention:  Database table names should be the lowercased plural version of the model name (model User automatically uses the database table users).  All primary keys are assumed to be `id`, and foreign keys are the singular version of the lower-cased model names with `_id` appended to them (`user_id`).  If you follow this convention, then you can declare your relationships with just one parameter:

```
public function ip()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Ip');
}
```

You can absolutely ignore these conventions, and there are ways of overriding them in the code, though it makes much more sense to adhere to these conventions and not have to worry about all of those extra parameters.

**Update**

According to your schema, you don't have a `hasOne` relationship, but you have a `hasMany` relationship.  If it was a `hasOne`, there would be an `ip_id` inside of your user's table (indicating a one-to-one relationship).  Since a single user can have many IPs, update this relationship to be:

```
return $this->hasMany('Ip');
```

And see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: I changed the field to user_id to fit the conventions and save myself some typing! I'm still experiencing the issue though. I wonder at this point if I am misunderstanding this at a deeper level.    My table 'users' has no field for reference to the table 'ips'. 'ips' has a foreign key that links the field 'user_id' to the 'id' field of the 'users' table.

Comment: I wonder if the user instance itself actually has any Ip entries associated with it? Could you update your question with the database schema of your `users` and `ips` tables?

Comment: The part that is throwing me is that if I just do: {{{ $user->ip }}} I get a response with the correct row from the 'ips' table. Its giving me the impression i'm on the correct track but I might be wrong on that.

Comment: do you have a column in the users table for `ip` ? If so, then eloquent is fetching _that_ and not the associated entry in `ips`

Comment: I don't have a column for ip in the users table. I'm currently looking up the format to post database schemas in so I can add it to the question.

Comment: That definitely changes things. However, I am now getting the following error:  Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$ip_addr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61070/discussion-between-watcher-and-tom-mcdonald).